# Integration of Stripe into Web Application

Tags: web-applications, architecture, stripe-payments

I am building a web application which uses `stripe-js` to process payments on the front end (only 1 product). I call the `stripe.createToken(card);` function to obtain a token which I subsequently pass to the back-end to create a charge. Currently I have a form which is as follows:

```
First Name: 
Last Name:
Email: 
Card (provided by stripe-js):
```

I want to be able to provide a refund to the customer, but I don't know how to best solve this problem. The stripe [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/refunds#api) require me to provide the id the charge. Is this the id of the token generated by `stripe.createToken`?



**Also, I have a user which is authenticated during the time the above form is being completed, so for refunds should I store the user id and token id and retrieve it and call the refund function when a refund is requested?**




**Is it ever a good idea to share the id of the token generated on the front end to the customer? I was thinking of this in case I simply call the refund API with the inputted token, but this seems like it has great potential for abuse.**




**Does Stripe allow for refunds to have a fixed time, such as within (7 days of the purchase)?**

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a new application, I would strongly recommend you build using the newer [Payment Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents) and [Payment Methods](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods) (for example following [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment)), instead of the tokens & charges APIs. The newer APIs fully support [Strong Customer Authentication](https://stripe.com/docs/strong-customer-authentication) and are Stripe's recommended integration pattern.

Regarding Refunds, yes you need to [specify either a Payment Intent or Charge ID](https://stripe.com/docs/api/refunds/create) to be refunded. Payment Intent would be recommended here, as well. If you continue to use Charges & Tokens, you would *not* use the token but rather the [Charge id](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-id).

How you manage your Customers & Payment Intents (or Charges) is up to you. If you [provide a `customer` when creating a Payment Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-customer) ([or Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create#create_charge-customer)), you can later [list all Payment Intents filtered to just that Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/list#list_payment_intents-customer) ([or Charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list#list_charges-customer)).

Refunds are controlled by your integration, so if you want to offer a refund for only 7 days that is up to you. You can read more about [handling failed Refunds](https://stripe.com/docs/refunds#failed-refunds) in the docs.